# Google Play Console,Can't see Ads on Pre launch reports

Tags: android, cordova, admob, appodeal, prelaunch

Lately after uploading two Apk versions, checking the Pre launch reports, I coulnd't see any Ads on the reports. we use Ad-mediation (Appodeal) that works well on our older verisons. Could be that google Firebase automation doesn't show Ads anymore as they used to? or is something wrong with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onDeviceReady() {
var appKey = "xxx";

document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

Appodeal.setOnLoadedTriggerBoth(adTypes, true);
Appodeal.setAutoCache(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL, false);
Appodeal.initialize(appKey, Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL | Appodeal.BANNER);
Appodeal.cache(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL);
Appodeal.enableInterstitialCallbacks(true);
Appodeal.show(Appodeal.BANNER_BOTTOM);

//after init
Appodeal.isLoaded(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL, function(result){
if (result == true)
Appodeal.show(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL);
})

};

</script>
```